# How to weight values in a range with swift?

Tags: swift, algorithm

How can I map values from a range to another?

```
// 1...55 maps to 0.0...0.25, 56...121 to 0.25...0.75 and 122...300 to 0.75...1.0:

    let values = 1...300
    mapValue(55) == 0.25
    mapValue(121) == 0.75
    mapValue(300) == 1.0
```

Comment: Where are you having trouble mapping it?

Comment: Do you want to map the values within the ranges linearly? or makes a dictionary of closed ranges? Or do polynomial interpolation?

Comment: How would I implement polynomial interpolation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Linear Interpolation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vdsp/linear_interpolation_functions/use_linear_interpolation_to_construct_new_data_points) provided by the Accelerate framework. The following snippet would generate a `result` array with xs spaced by a certain stride :

```
import Accelerate

let xs: [Float] = [1.0, 55.0, 121.0, 300.0]
let ys: [Float] = [0.0, 0.25, 0.75, 1.0]

let n = vDSP_Length(xs.last! - xs.first!)
let stride = vDSP_Stride(1)

var result = [Float](repeating: 0,
                     count: Int(n))

vDSP_vgenp(ys, stride,
           xs, stride,
           &result, stride,
           n,
           vDSP_Length(xs.count))

let approx = result[100]  //0.5909091
```

You could also add smoothing or use quadratic interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, i came up with this:

```
let mappings: [ClosedRange<Double> : ClosedRange<Double>] = [1...55 : 0...0.25, 56...121 : 0.25...0.75, 122...300 : 0.75...1.0]
func transform(_ x: Double) -> Double {
    guard let (source, destination) = (mappings.first { $0.key.contains(x) }) else { return 1.0 }

    let a = source.lowerBound
    let b = source.upperBound
    let c = destination.lowerBound
    let d = destination.upperBound
    return (x-a)*(d-c)/(b-a)+c
}
```

Comment: @matt I was typing in Xcode while you posted the solution. You helped me a lot, nevertheless. Thank you!